# Debugging office.js in Word 2016

Tags: word-addins

Using Office.js in Word 2016 and reading the document content.  The code works in Office 365 and also it allows that browser allows to inspect the code and see the logs. But the same is not allowed in Word 2016. Can some one suggest how to debug the code in Word 2016?

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved and got the help from the below link. It helped to debug on office desktop

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10